# verb+x ray. A better verb than doing

Tags: synonyms

I am currently working on a presentation, which is about a diagnosis of a type of disease. However, I am not sure about the word that put in front of "x-rays". Is there a better phrase which has the similar meaning to "doing x-rays"? Does "Conducting x-rays" work? This is a kinda homework+synonym question, but I didn't find tag for homework.
Thanks for your help

Comment: In general what is used for photographs is OK for x-rays. I would use *take*, as in "I *took* photos of all the buildings.", or "We took *x-rays* of his leg."

Comment: "to X-ray" is a transitive verb in English; see [Collins.](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/x-ray) _We **x-rayed** her abdomen._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procedural x-rays are often described as

> We **took** x-rays of all patients with...
>   We **performed** x-rays **on** all patients with...